# Load resized bitmap into byte[] array

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, picasso, android-glide

I have to send a downscaled bitmap to my database from Android (using Xamarin).

To do so, I read about Glide or Picasso. Glide seemed to be the best picture library so I've installed Glide-Xamarin 3.7.0.

But I don't get how to load an existing bitmap (from URI), downscale to specific[ish] resolution and save it into a byte[] array in order to send it with the Webservice I'm calling.

If anyone knows the recipe for that one, would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this... but some of the methods aren't available with my Xamarin library :/

I don't have access to AsBitmap() and  ToBytes()
---
`Glide.with(context)
    .load(“/user/profile/photo/path”)
    .asBitmap()
    .toBytes()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<byte[]>(250, 250) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(byte[] data, GlideAnimation anim) {
            // Post your bytes to a background thread and upload them here.
        }
    });`
---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it with Picasso

```
var bitmap = Picasso
             .With(context)
             .Load(originalBitmapUri)
             .Resize(reqWidth, reqHeight)
             .CenterInside()
             .OnlyScaleDown()
             .Get();
```

This one-liner returns me a resized Bitmap, from which I can call CompressAsync(.)

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, quality, stream);
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```